# In AWS, How to get the availability zone Id given a name from within a Fargate task

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-fargate

I'm running a java service on ECS Fargate. In it, I need to get the availability zone ID that the task is running in. I did the following:

```java
public static String getZoneId() {
    final String METADATA_URL = System.getenv("ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4") + "/task";
    try {
        final JsonObject jsonElement = getJsonInfo(METADATA_URL);
        final String availabilityZone = jsonElement
                .getAsJsonPrimitive("AvailabilityZone").getAsString();

        try(Ec2Client ec2 = buildEc2Client()) {
            return getAzIdFromName(ec2, availabilityZone);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //...
    }
}

private static JsonObject getJsonInfo(String url) throws IOException {
    final String body;
    try (final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        try (final InputStream bodyStream = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
            body = IOUtils.toString(bodyStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }
    return JsonParser.parseString(body).getAsJsonObject();
}

private static Ec2Client buildEc2Client() throws IOException {
    final String CREDENTIALS_URL = "http://169.254.170.2" + System.getenv("AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI");
    final JsonObject body = getJsonInfo(CREDENTIALS_URL);
    AwsRegionProvider regionProvider = new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain();
    AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = () -> AwsSessionCredentials.create(
            body.getAsJsonPrimitive("AccessKeyId").getAsString(),
            body.getAsJsonPrimitive("SecretAccessKey").getAsString(),
            body.getAsJsonPrimitive("Token").getAsString()
    );
    return Ec2Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .region(regionProvider.getRegion())
            .build();
}

private static String getAzIdFromName(Ec2Client ec2Client, String azName) {
    DescribeAvailabilityZonesRequest request = DescribeAvailabilityZonesRequest.builder()
            .zoneNames(azName)
            .build();
    final DescribeAvailabilityZonesResponse describeAvailabilityZonesResponse = ec2Client.describeAvailabilityZones(request);
    return describeAvailabilityZonesResponse.availabilityZones().get(0).zoneId();
}
```

Running the above on successfully gets the availability zone name. But then when the `Ec2Client::describeAvailabilityZones` is called, I get:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 [ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/52.94.136.219] failed: Connect timed out
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
```

The task is not connected to the internet. I'd expect the endpoint to be accessable internally (not going out to the internet and in again). But I'm not sure. I don't even know if this is the issue.

How do I get the zone Id given a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, It turns out that Ec2Client is not getting the zone id from some metadata local endpoint, it is actually communicating (trying to) with the EC2 service endpoint. This means that for the request to go through, the VPC hosting my ECS cluster needs to have an endpoint for EC2 service (same as I did for ECR for example).

Doing so, made the request pass and I get the zone id in return. No changes in the code itself was needed.